# Shortest Paths with Resource Constraints

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, np-complete

I have a directed acyclic graph and need to find the shortest paths with resource constraints. My constraint is that the paths selected must have a minimum number of a set resource consumed.

Currently I am using [Yen's K Shortest Path algorithm](http://mansci.journal.informs.org/content/17/11/712.abstract) to calculate K shortest paths and then only accept those that satisfy my constraint. The issue here is in guessing K, as if it is incorrectly chosen, it is possible that no feasible paths will be found.

I have found quite a lot of literature on this topic, [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.101.7348&rep=rep1&type=pdf) provides a good overview I think. However, I am struggling to make sense of it and find a concise algorithm that is able to be implemented (I am using Python, however any clear algorithmic ideas would be great).

I understand that this problem is NP-Complete, and as such I am interested in any good approximation algorithms as well as exact approaches.

Anyone have any good recommendations?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by resource constraints?  It doesn't seem like this problem would be NP-hard if those constraints have certain formats.

Comment: I am not only trying to find the shortest paths, but a path that satisfies a constraint (only one for now while I'm getting it working, but possibly more in the future). This is a min constraint.

Each node N, in the graph contributes x to the total resource count, N_x.

For a path to be valid, sum (N_x) >= Min, for all N in the path.

Comment: Your overview link doesn't work for me, but have you tried Eppstein's k-shortest-paths algorithm?  It doesn't require limiting k in advance, but generates the shortest paths one by one, and you can simply keep generating them until you find one that satisfies your constraints.

Comment: Thanks @han, I think I've fixed the link to the overview if you were interested in checking it out. I have not tried Eppstein's k-shortest-path algorithm, but reading through his paper now and it is looking like a good alternative to Yen's.

Do you know of a freely available implementation? I'll go through in detail eventually, but it'd be cool to compare to Yen's quickly on my problem if possible...

Comment: You may also be interested in Jiménez's k-shortest-paths algorithm ("Recursive Enumeration Algorithm"), which is much simpler than Eppstein's algorithm and faster in practice (but asymptotically slower).

Comment: @user613954: Sorry, I have implemented it once for an employer, but I don't know of a good free implementation. According to a quick google search there is [at least one free implementation](http://code.google.com/p/k-shortest-path/)...

Comment: Han: Thanks for the implementation, I missed it in my search and it looks very helpful. And thank you Nabb for the mention of Jiménez, I'll certainly look into that also.

Comment: How many nodes and edges do you have? What kind of complexities are you willing to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to transform your graph `(V,E)` into `(V',E')` where

- `P(v)` is the price of the original node `v`
- `R` is the maximum resource use.
- `V' = {(v,k) | v in V and k in [0..R]}`
- `E'((v,k),(w,l)) = E(v,w) and k+P(w)=l`

Then you do a dijkstra search from `(v0,P(v0))`. If it was possible to find a path to `v1`, given the limit, the shortest distance to it, will be the shortest among the `(v1,k)` vertices.

You obviously don't create the actual expanded graph. What would be going on in your modified dijkstra is that in addition to the distance so far, you would keep the resource use so far as well. You would only follow a path if it didn't exceed the limit. And instead of keeping a `dist[v]` you would keep `dist[v,k]` representing the shortest path to v so far, using exactly `k` resources.

If your resource bound is very large, this can potentially grow as big. Hence the NP completeness. However if your resource bound is small, or you don't mind rounding of to nearest 10, 100 or 1000, it will run in fast polynomial time.
Especially if you implement the optimization of stopping once you've reached a useable `(v1,k)`.

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem as a k-shortest path suffers from the fact that you don't know how to choose `k`.

Solving it as the accepted answer proposes, suffers from the fact that you need to maintain `dist[v,k]` for potentially all values of k from all distinct paths arriving from the source to node v (which results in very inefficient algorithm).

There are pseudo-polynomial time algorithms for solving this problem, which is called, as you'd expect, "Shortest Path Problem with Resource Constraints" (SPPRC). The problem appears often in Vehicle Routing Problems (VRP) and Crew Pairing Problems (both are transportation problems, that are mostly dealt with in Operations Research). For a starting point see the following (review) paper: S. Irnich & G. Desaulniers, "Shortest Path Problems with Resource Constraints", In G. Desaulniers, J. Desrosiers, M. Solomon (eds): Column Generation, Springer, 2005.

You can google for the title of the paper, and you should be able to download it for free.  I should mention though that your problem has an unusual constraint structure: namely, you need to "spend" at least a certain amount of a resource instead of making sure you don't spend "too much" of a resource...